# Contribution Email Attachment Name

Tags: wordpress, attachments

My client would like to change the attachment name of the pdf they receive when a contribution is made.

This is now receipt.pdf (which is the case for a lot of emails).

Can this be changed?

I'm using Wordpress

Answer (score 3):

I didn't manage to test this but Receipt.pdf is been hard-coded in CiviCRM Core and if you need to change the name of the attachment then you need to look into the below file and you need to override the file to achieve your change

.../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/confirm.php

'PDFFilename' => 'receipt.pdf' - Line 1274

Also look into the link before overriding the file

[Can I override core classes or PHP files with custom versions?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/can-i-override-core-classes-or-php-files-with-custom-versions)

I guess this helps!