# Where to change details on payment processor?

Tags: payment-processor, payment

I am using Wordpress 4.8.1 and CiviCRM 4.7.22.
Please see the screen shot of my payment processor on a contribution page.  I am using Paypal Payments Pro. You will see where it says click the **"Continue"** button on the bottom.  The button on the bottom says **"Contribute"**.  That is very unprofessional.  Where can I fix that?

Thank you
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the exact filename of the text, you can simply grep inside the civicrm directory -

```
$ grep -rl "If you have a PayPal account" templates/
templates/CRM/Financial/Form/PaypalPro.tpl
```

Which gives the result of [this file](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Financial/Form/PaypalPro.tpl#L29). You need to either -

1. Change the `Continue` text and create a PR to get it accepted into core.
2. Override this file [into an extension](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/can-i-override-core-classes-or-php-files-with-custom-versions). (Not recommended based on Coleman's explanation on the link.)
3. Write a simple js in an ext and change the text of the paypal msg or the `Contribute` button.