# List unassigned Inbound SMS activities

Tags: sms, civisms

I'm facing the same issue as spidersilk in this old question - [Is there a way to add a custom field to the Inbound SMS activity type?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/826/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-custom-field-to-the-inbound-sms-activity-type). Trying to keep the one CiviCRM instance I support as "out of the box" as possible, so hoping for an answer that doesn't require custom status-es or CiviRules.

Is there an "out of the box" way to search for activities with a blank "Assigned To?" With that, I could just list activities of type "Inbound SMS" that have yet to be assigned. I realize assignment isn't the end, but it'll suffice. I had high hopes for the Search Builder but, to my surprise, Assigned To is not one of the fields exposed for Activity.

CiviCRM 5.21.0 on Drupal 7.69.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not meet your needs but it can be done from the Support menu under api4 explorer (but not api3). Choose activity - get, and then for the where clause pick assignees.id Is Null. Then click execute. Note on a stock install the screen will look weird but it functions.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but a very valid approach. Thanks.